# My pc is very slow

Tags: windows-10, performance, desktop-computer

my pc performance became very slow lately just doing basic tasks like browsing on the internet, watching 720p youtube videos, working with MS word or excel, for example it hangs for few secs when I'm just opening a new tab on chrome, my cpu usage while watching 720p videos on youtube goes to 100% but temp is usually at 50C. Even opening calculator takes at least 15 seconds...
What I've tried so far to increase performance is increasing virtual memory size,disabling some useless windows animations and cortana too as well, cleaning cache and temp files every day,I've no useless software that would decrease my performance, only the most used ones,scanning viruses at least twice a week but no viruses, disabling hardware accelerator in chrome..As well as clean reinstalling Windows 10 but it helped only for a short time, then my performance became slow again.And I would really like to know a reason why my pc performance is so slow, if my ram never goes full? (I always check task manager), disk space isn't full too, it has plenty of space free

My pc specs:
AMD phenom II 955 BE (Quad Core) CPU
AMD Radeon 5750 GPU
6GB RAM
1TB HDD

I also forgot to mention that I'm cleaning dusts regularly too

Comment: Sounds like your HDD is starting to fail, I suggest you replace it, before you lose data

Comment: I agree it looks like a bad HDD, but I would check for evidence before buying a new drive. Use a program that gets the SMART status of drives like Crystal DiskInfo, and/or any built-in hardware tests. Dell machines for example have built in hardware diagnostics available from the F12 boot menu.

Comment: Thank you but according to Crystal DiskInfo my HDD health is good.

Comment: How old is your HDD?

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU usage**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO**, **Resident Set** and click to start. Now capture 1 minute of the slow Windows. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: have you captured a trace of the slowness?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 likely candidates -

The Hard drive (which I acknowledge you have already says claims its healthy - it could still be faulty - check if the hard drive light is solid on when the problem is occuring).  It could also be full - when hard drives get past 80% they start slowing down, markedly so after 90%

It could be that your heatsink is not properly attached to your CPU, and your CPU is getting hot and throttling right down.   You may want to stress test the CPU and see how fast it performs and/or monitor clock rates on it.